# Ruby On Rails custom route always redirects to controller's show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am attempting to create a new route so that I can utilize RoR's path variable feature i.e. **new_game_path**. In my case, I want to use **load_game_path**

I have created an action for the appropriate controller and currently routed like so:

```
resources :games do
    get 'load', on: :collection
end
```

Every time I use the **load_games_path** it uses the correct URI but appears to redirect to the GamesController's show action and displays the Games' inherit show view.

I have checked **rake routes** and I see my newly created route with what seems to be the desired path /games/load (file path: /views/games/load.html.erb)

```
load_games GET    /games/load(.:format)       games#load/
```

Rake Routes:

```
    welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)    welcome#index
      players GET    /players(.:format)          players#index
              POST   /players(.:format)          players#create
   new_player GET    /players/new(.:format)      players#new
  edit_player GET    /players/:id/edit(.:format) players#edit
       player GET    /players/:id(.:format)      players#show
              PUT    /players/:id(.:format)      players#update
              DELETE /players/:id(.:format)      players#destroy
        games GET    /games(.:format)            games#index
              POST   /games(.:format)            games#create
     new_game GET    /games/new(.:format)        games#new
    edit_game GET    /games/:id/edit(.:format)   games#edit
         game GET    /games/:id(.:format)        games#show
              PUT    /games/:id(.:format)        games#update
              DELETE /games/:id(.:format)        games#destroy
        users GET    /users(.:format)            users#index
              POST   /users(.:format)            users#create
     new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)        users#new
    edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
         user GET    /users/:id(.:format)        users#show
              PUT    /users/:id(.:format)        users#update
              DELETE /users/:id(.:format)        users#destroy
                     /players/:name(.:format)    players#index
   load_games GET    /games/load(.:format)       games#load
              GET    /games(.:format)            games#index
              POST   /games(.:format)            games#create
              GET    /games/new(.:format)        games#new
              GET    /games/:id/edit(.:format)   games#edit
              GET    /games/:id(.:format)        games#show
              PUT    /games/:id(.:format)        games#update
              DELETE /games/:id(.:format)        games#destroy
         root        /                           welcome#index
```

routes.rb:

```
     get "welcome/index"

     resources :players, :games, :users

     match '/players/:name'  => 'players#index'

     # match 'games/load(.:format)', :controller => 'games', :action => 'load'

      resources :games do
        collection do
          get 'load'
        end
      end

root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

I am aware that load is a pre-defined action for the controller. Just to make sure this wasn't an issue, I tried an arbitrary name for the action - yielding the same results.

I've also tried this with no success:

```
match 'games/load(.:format)', :controller => 'games', :action => 'load'
```

Comment: What does the log say? It will tell you which action is being called.

Comment: Here is a snippet of the log. You can see it is trying to call the show action. Not sure what the HTML id => 'load' parameter means.

'
Started GET "/games/load" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-25 21:07:36 -0400
Processing by GamesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"load"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template games/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "W:/Rails/testApp/blog/app/views"
):
  actionpack  '

Comment: Could you paste the `rake routes` result here? Only those related to games and with the perserved order. Because I'm thinking if it is posible that you have another path "unintentionally" catched the route and passed to show action

Comment: Of course. I have now included rake routes in the original post

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
resources :games do
  collection do
    get 'load'
  end
end
```

Right now it's interpreting 'games/load' as 'games/:id' with the :id parameter set to 'load', and routing 'games/:id' to GamesController#show.

Edit: And make sure there's not another call to `resources :games` earlier in the routes file, even if :games is just one of several arguments like `resources :players, :games`, because you won't be able to insert the collection method later if there is.

Comment: The same result. I tried member do as well and that returned the following error: 

`No route matches {:action=>"load", :controller=>"games"}`

I see what you are saying, that must be why it is calling the show action? Because it thinks I am attempting to display a specific "game"? When really I just want to display a specific subpage of games.

Comment: With collection, do you get the same result including the same message in the log (processing by GamesController#show)?

Comment: collection does yield the same result: `Missing template games/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "W:/Rails/testApp/blog/app/views"` the log says processing by GamesController#show

Comment: like you said, I think the system thinks I'm trying to pass a game, i.e. games/1/show.html.erb. In reality, I just want to display a subpage of /games/ (../games/load.html.erb). I didn't think it would be this difficult, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Try @PeterWong's suggestion - in fact go ahead and paste the contents of config/routes.rb too.

Comment: I have gone ahead and included both in the original post.

Comment: I bet your problem is `resources :players, :games, :users` - with :games in that list, it's ignoring the redefinition later when you try to add the collection method. Change that top line to `resources :players, :users` and you're golden.

Comment: You are correct! First created -> highest importance correct? So my earlier definitions were ignored. Such a ridiculous problem... appreciate all the feedback. Is it possible to include this in the initial answer for future reference?

Comment: Crucial detail for me is that the new custom route be placed *ABOVE* the basic `resources :games` in the routes file, or else like you it would keep defaulting to the `#show` action.